# How to get the value for each key in dictionary in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm maintaining a `NSMutableDictionary` which holds key and value pair.Now i need to perform some operation for each value in it.How to retrive value from dictionary.

```
// this is NSMutableDIctionary 
NSMutableDictionary *dictobj = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 // in methodA

-(void)methodA
{
   //get the value for each key and peform an operation on it.
}
```

How to proceed? plz help

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
for (id key in dictobj)
{
    id value = [dictobj objectForKey:key];
    [value doSomething];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not entirely clear what your question is asking, but you might be looking for:

```
for (id currentValue in [dictobj allValues])
{
    //stuff with currentValue
}
```

Comment: wher is currentValue declared? of which class object is it?

Comment: This is a use of "fast enumeration" (just like the other answer). `currentValue` is declared right in the for-in loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [viewControllers allValues];
for (int i = 0; i<array.count; i++) {        
    MenuListingVC *vc = array[i];
    [vc tableDataReload];
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to make the answer more understandable.