# How to get the value for each key in UIView in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286186/how-to-get-the-value-for-each-key-in-dictionary-in-objective-c), I'm trying to do the same but this time I need the values and properties of a UIView, how can this be done?

```
// myView == UIView

for (id key in myView)
{
    id value = [myView objectForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: Check out this article:
http://forrst.com/posts/Getting_a_dictionary_of_an_NSObjects_property_n-h2T

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware of the description method most objects have- it returns a string with a bunch of properties of the object and their values.

```
NSLog(@"View properties are %@", [yourViewObject description]);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? The message in the log is empty (after the "View properties are"

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to this: NSObject Protocol Reference at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html . So if your getting blank your problem is probably that your reference to your view object is set to nil at the time of your NSLog message

Comment: In other words, if(yourViewObject == nil) NSLog(@"It's nil"); is probably going to work